# React Router CSSTransitionGroup works only on transitionAppear

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Routing works just fine but animated transitions don't with an exception for an `transitionAppear` (it works on any page if i open it directly by opening a specific url). My goal is to animate transitions when user changes pages by clicking on `Link` in `mainNavBar.jsx` component. What am I doing wrong here? Is my project structure fine or do I need any rearrangements?

My main `app.js` component:

```
import React from 'react';

import {About} from "./components/jsx/about";
import {BackgroundVideo} from "./components/jsx/backgroundVideo";
import {Landing} from "./components/jsx/landing";
import {Studios} from "./components/jsx/studios";
import Work from "./components/jsx/work";

import {CSSTransitionGroup} from 'react-transition-group'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <BackgroundVideo/>
                <CSSTransitionGroup
                    transitionName="transition"
                    transitionAppear={true}
                    transitionAppearTimeout={500}
                    transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                    transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
                    <Switch location={this.props.location}>
                        <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
                        <Route exact path="/work" component={Work}/>
                    </Switch>
                </CSSTransitionGroup>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

First route component `about.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import face_classes from '../css/face.module.css'
import about_classes from '../css/about.module.css'
import {MainNavBar} from "./mainNavBar";
import {Footer} from "./footer";

export const About = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <MainNavBar/>
            {/* some component content is here */}
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Second route component `work.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {MainNavBar} from "./mainNavBar";
import {Footer} from "./footer";

class Work extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MainNavBar/>
                {/* some component content is here */}
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Work.propTypes = {};

export default Work;
```

`mainNavBar.jsx` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export const MainNavBar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            {/*some component content is here*/}
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li key={1}><Link to="/about">ABOUT</Link></li>
                    <li key={2}><Link to="/work">WORK</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Transitions `index.css`:

```
.transition-appear {
    opacity: 0.01;
}

.transition-appear.transition-appear-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.transition-enter {
    opacity: 0.01;
}

.transition-enter.transition-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.transition-leave {
    opacity: 1;
}

.transition-leave.transition-leave-active {
    opacity: 0.01;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by placing page component's (`about.jsx`, `work.jsx`) directly inside another `CSSTransitionGroup` tags.